# Check if SQL integer field is empty

Tags: android, sql, integer, field

I try to get an Item out of my SQL db in android, everything goes well, the only thing I am struggling with is to get the INTEGER value is there is nothing filled in in the DB (null?)

So I first initialize it, then get the Integer value out of the DB and then assign it to an instance of my class. I was once told that if it will get nothing out of the DB it will keep the initialized value, but this might be wrong? I use now:

```
int score = 100;
score = c.getInt(11);
q.setScore(score);
```

Comment: and if c is your cursor than see how you wrote query to select from table.Is there any data in the table.Data in 11 th column is integer type?

Comment: C is indeed the cursor, it is collecting data for sure, I can assure you that the field is empty (if I export the database from device I see an empty SQL field) and the type is Numeric ... by typing this I realize that this might be the problem? Or is Numeric ok? q is my instance of my class.
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
   Question q = new Question();

Comment: If the field is empty then what number do you expect `getInt` to return? I guess it will return `null` so you will loose the old value(`100`)

Comment: 100 as pointed int my code above.. if there is actually a value in the DB it should set the score var of that instance to the value of the db..

Comment: Is it possible to post the query you used to create the db?

Comment: c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE _ID =" + id
    + " AND LEVEL = " + level, null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I was once told that if it will get nothing out of the DB it will keep the initialized value*

That is true for Embedded SQL. You seem to be using a resultset object, so it is not true.
Resultset  objects typically return 0 if you try to get a numeric null value from a column.

Use `c.wasNull()` to check if the value you just read was `null` and not `0`.

**EDIT** (added the code from Jack's comment):

```
int score; 
if (c.isNull(11)) { 
  score = 100; 
} else { 
  score = c.getInt(11); 
} 
q.setScore(score);
```

Comment: I am using this configuration for the sql db: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ ... is this embedded?

Comment: int score;
   
   if (c.isNull(11)){ score = 100;
   } else {
    score = c.getInt(11);
   }
   q.setScore(score); This solved it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt(int)

> *public abstract int **getInt** (int columnIndex) Since: API Level 1 Returns the value of the requested column as an int. The result and
>   whether this method throws an exception when the column value is null,
>   the column type is not an integral type, or the integer value is
>   outside the range [Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE] is
>   implementation-defined. Parameters columnIndex    the zero-based index of
>   the target column. Returns the value of that column as an int.*